# How to extract data schema from json-ld format to generate html form

Tags: javascript, html, json-ld

So I am new to linked web and linked data.
I have a data schema on remote server that is written in json-ld. I have to et that data and generate html forms based on t. I have actually tried rdforms and callimachus library and both haven't helped me much. Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "data schema"? A vocabulary? The way RDF works, it is, generally speaking, not possible to generate forms from a vocabulary. You might be interested in [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/), which allows you to do that. Have a look at the [HydraConsole with an exemplary event API](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/console/?url=http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/event-api). It should do most of the stuff you need. If you have further Hydra-related questions, feel free to join the Hydra W3C Community Group and post them directly to our mailing list.

*Disclaimer: I'm the original creater of Hydra and chair of the Hydra W3C Community Group. I'm also one of the core designers of JSON-LD.*

Comment: Hi. No. I meant that I have generated a template using different vocabularies. Now I want to use this template to generate an html form with constraints. I will check Hydra. Thanks.